# Apache POI - Constraint on text length to be 8 OR 10

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I would like to add the folloqing constraints to a column:

1. text length should be of length 8 OR 10
2. all the digits should be number BUT the type of the column is string

Do you think is possible?

Here I have set the column to be string

```
DataFormat fmt = wb.createDataFormat();
CellStyle textStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
textStyle.setDataFormat(fmt.getFormat("@"));
sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(1, textStyle);
```

Then I have added the following constraint

```
XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) dvHelper.createTextLengthConstraint(ComparisonOperator.EQUAL, "8", null);
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(-1, -1, 1, 1);
XSSFDataValidation validation = (XSSFDataValidation)dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

but is not working and I don't know how to add the constraint that to be equal to 8 or 10, nor that the digits should be numbers.

Thanks a lot

Comment: How would you do the constraint in Excel? What happens if you specify it the same way in Apache POI?

Comment: In excel you have to do it with the option above (not functions)

Comment: Create the constraint you want in Excel, read it back with Apache POI, and see how Excel decides to encode it into the file format?

Comment: Hint: `operatorType` in [DataValidationHelper.createTextLengthConstraint](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataValidationHelper.html#createTextLengthConstraint-int-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) is **not** `ComparisonOperator` which is a `byte` but [DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataValidationConstraint.OperatorType.html) which is a `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this, t's not exactly like i wanted but is acceptable:

```
dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) dvHelper.createNumericConstraint(ValidationType.TEXT_LENGTH, OperatorType.BETWEEN, "8", "10");
addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(-1, -1, 1, 1);
validation = (XSSFDataValidation)dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
sheet2.addValidationData(validation);
```